# Infinite series - analytical solution

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions

Analytical Solution is required for:

1. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)\exp(-n(n+1)x),$$
2. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)^2\exp(-n(n+1)x),$$
3. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n+1)(2n+1)\exp(-n(n+1)x),$$
4. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n+1)(2n+1)^2\exp(-n(n+1)x).$$

For clarity, series no. 1 is: $1+3\exp(-2x)+5\exp(-6x)+\ldots$.

I am a Chemical Engineer and the analytical solution of this problem is of high interest to reaction dynamics theory.

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed.

Answer (score 3):

Your second series equals $$-(1/2)e^{x/4}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}θ_2(z,e^{−x})|_{z=0},$$ where $θ_2$ is the second theta function, see Whittaker, Watson, vol. 2, 21.11. 
Probably the other 3 series can be also expressed in terms of theta functions.

Comment: And if you don't have Whittaker & Watson handy, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html

Comment: On my opinion, every serious engineer has to have Wittaker Watson handy:-)